# How to get content of message body of email into spreadsheet using App Script?

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I want to get the content of email into spreadsheet using App script.

Mail body format is like this :
Account : xyz
Address : 12xyz
Mail Id : xyz@gmail.com
Id : 1234

I want to add this info into different columns of spreadsheet using App script.

Below is my script

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Exclusion Check");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<1; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var content = messages[j].getPlainBody();
      if (content) {
      var tmp
      tmp = content.match(/Account:\n([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var account = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'NULL';

      tmp = content.match(/Address:\n([\s\S]+)/);
      var address = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'NULL';

      tmp = content.match(/MDM ID:\n([0-9]*$)/);
      var mdmId = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'NULL';

      tmp = content.match(/NPI ID:\n([\s\S]+)/);
      var npiId = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'NULL';

      tmp = content.match(/Active State Licenses:\n([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
      var activeStateLicenses = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'NULL';

      tmp = content.match(/Requested by:\n([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
      var requestedBy = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'NULL';

      tmp = content.match(/Requestor e-mail:\n([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
      var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'NULL';
      
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();

      ss.appendRow([account,address,mdmId,npiId,activeStateLicenses,requestedBy, email,sub,dat])
      }
    }
      // threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me in this ?!

I tried using content.match() function but it is showing me NULL result according to above script.
I don't where the error is.

Comment: Please provide a several example email messages

Comment: If you can control the content of the original email do yourself a favor and provide a valid JSON string between two unique delimiters.  It makes it easy to find and easy to use.